# Need assistance in rewriting a SQL query

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema, snowflake-connector

```
Select ID,LISTAGG(CATEGORY_CD, ',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY CAST(P_NO as INT)) AS CATEGORY_CD
FROM table1
WHERE DATE = '2022-02-02'
AND CATEGORY_FLAG = '0'
AND CAT_SRC_CD NOT IN ('0','1','2','3')
group by ID
```

I need to rewrite the above query, such that it should be ORDERED BY P_NO
and I need to display distinct values for CATEGORY_CD column.

I tried the logic mentioned below and I used ORDER BY P_NO in the sub query. Not sure if the logic I have written is correct.

```
SELECT ID,LISTAGG(distinct CATEGORY_CD, ',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY CAST(CATEGORY_CD as INT)) AS CATEGORY_CD
 FROM 
      (SELECT distinct ID,CREATE_DT,CATEGORY_CD, 
          TRY_CAST(P_NO as INTEGER) as P_NO
        FROM table1 
        WHERE DATE = '2022-02-02'
        AND CATEGORY_FLAG = '0'
        AND CAT_SRC_CD NOT IN ('0','1','2','3')
        ORDER BY P_NO
      ) 
    GROUP BY 
      ID;
```

The original query which I have mentioned is giving the below results. I should display only distinct values for CATEGORY_CD column and the results should be ORDERED BY P_NO column.

```
      ID                CATEGORY_CD
      
      169174408          5,5,5,5
      169174408          2,1,1
      169174408          12,12,12,12,12,12
      839946105          2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3
```

Kindly guide me in implementing the correct logic. Thanks in advance :)

Also, please guide me if I need to add another few columns to my original query. I have added my original SQL query again adding another column.

```
Select ID,LISTAGG(CATEGORY_CD, ',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY CAST(P_NO as INT)) AS CATEGORY_CD,
LISTAGG(CATEGORY_DTL, ',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY CAST(P_NO as INT)) AS CATEGORY_DTL
FROM table1
WHERE DATE = '2022-02-02'
AND CATEGORY_FLAG = '0'
AND CAT_SRC_CD NOT IN ('0','1','2','3')
group by ID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `QUALIFY` to select distinct `CATEGORY_CD` per `ID`:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM table1
    WHERE DATE = '2022-02-02'
      AND CATEGORY_FLAG = '0'
      AND CAT_SRC_CD NOT IN ('0','1','2','3')
    QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID,CATEGORY_CD ORDER BY P_NO::INT) = 1
)
SELECT ID,LISTAGG(CATEGORY_CD, ',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY P_NO::int) AS CATEGORY_CD
FROM cte
GROUP BY ID;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. Can you guide me the logic, if I want to add some additional columns to the SQL query?

Comment: Select ID,LISTAGG(CATEGORY_CD, ',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY CAST(P_NO as INT)) AS CATEGORY_CD,
LISTAGG(CATEGORY_DTL, ',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY CAST(P_NO as INT)) AS CATEGORY_DTL
FROM table1
WHERE DATE = '2022-02-02'
AND CATEGORY_FLAG = '0'
AND CAT_SRC_CD NOT IN ('0','1','2','3')
group by ID

Comment: I have added another column called CATEGORY_DTL.. Can you help me with the logic now please?

Comment: Please confirm if this is correct?                                                                                                    WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM table1
    WHERE DATE = '2022-02-02'
      AND CATEGORY_FLAG = '0'
      AND CAT_SRC_CD NOT IN ('0','1','2','3')
    QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID,CATEGORY_CD,CATEGORY_DTL ORDER BY P_NO::INT) = 1
)
SELECT ID,LISTAGG(CATEGORY_CD, ',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY P_NO::int) AS CATEGORY_CD,
LISTAGG(CATEGORY_DTL, ',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY P_NO::int) AS CATEGORY_DTL
FROM cte
GROUP BY ID;

Comment: @Jenifer This approach will not work for multiple columns for instance for CATEGORY_ID/CAGTEGORY_DTL: `(1,1), (1,2)` they are distinct as pair but not as single column

Comment: Could you please suggest an alternative solution that would work for multiple columns?

Comment: @Jenifer One solution could be perform the operation twice one column at a time and union all